# A theorem on restriction of a metric

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Consider $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Let $Y\subseteq X$ be a metric on itself and $E\subseteq Y$. Then there is a theorem which says that $E$ is open in $Y$ iff $E=Y\cap G$ for some open subset $G$ of the original space $G$. The intuition behind behind this condition is not clear. Why is that intersection is so special? I understand that $E$ being a subset of some open set of $X$ is not enough because a subset of a open set need not be an open set ?

Comment: This seems to just be a description of the subspace topology of Y in X.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something peculiar to metric spaces. If $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ is any topological space, and $Y\subseteq X$, we define the subspace (or relative) topology on $Y$ to be $\tau_Y=\{U\cap Y:U\in\tau\}$. This $\tau_Y$ is easily shown to be a topology on $Y$, and it is related to that of $X$ in the simplest way: in effect it is exactly what we can see of $\tau$ if our vision is limited to the set $Y$.

Now suppose that the topology $\tau$ is generated by a metric $d$; $d$ is a function from $X\times X$ to $\Bbb R$, so we can look at the restriction of $d$ to $Y\times Y$. Let $d_Y=d\upharpoonright Y\times Y$ be this restriction; then it’s easily verified that $d_Y$ is a metric on $Y$. This is the simplest way to get a metric on $Y$ that is naturally related to $d$; in fact, it is exactly what we can see of $d$ if our vision is limited to $Y$.

Now to tie the two notions together: it turns out (and is not hard to show) that the topology generated on $Y$ by $d_Y$ is exactly $\tau_Y$, the subspace topology on $Y$ defined from $\tau$.

Comment: M.Scott: I am not aware of the word "topology". Can you tell in some other way.

Comment: @prasenjit: If you start with a metric space $\langle X,d\rangle$, the associated topology on $X$ is the family $\tau$ of all open subsets of $X$. This $\tau$ has (among others) the following properties: $\varnothing\in\tau$; $X\in\tau$; if $U,V\in\tau$, then $U\cap V\in\tau$; and if $\mathscr{U}\subseteq\tau$, then $\bigcup\mathscr{U}\in\tau$. Families of subsets of $X$ that satisfy these conditions turn out to be very useful; they are called *topologies* on $X$, and a pair $\langle X,\tau\rangle$ such that $\tau$ satisfies the conditions is called ...

Comment: ... a [topological space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_space). But if you’ve not yet encountered topological spaces in general, the easiest way to say it is that the open sets in $Y$ according to the metric $d_Y$ are exactly the same as the sets of the form $U\cap Y$ with $U$ open in $X$.